# Algorithm for placing fixed element near 2 other elements on page without intersecting any of them

Tags: javascript

I need to place fixed element A near element B on the page, but must not overlap element C. I'm using getBoundingClientRect to get sizes of existing elements and I know with and height of new element A. I covered few common cases manually but it's not really universal as B and C can be anywhere, any sizes. I need a proper solution. Basically I need algorithm to place AABB (axis-aligned bounding box) closest to second AABB while not being covered by third AABB. And it must stay on page of course. B and C are often near edge which complicates it.

After covering several dozens of papers with rectangles, the best I could came up with is bruteforce:

```js
function aabbIntersects(a, b) {
  // return true if A and B intersects
  var ca = {
      x: a.x + a.width / 2,
      y: a.y + a.height / 2
    },
    cb = {
      x: b.x + b.width / 2,
      y: b.y + b.height / 2
    },
    dx = Math.abs(ca.x - cb.x) - (a.width + b.width) / 2,
    dy = Math.abs(ca.y - cb.y) - (a.height + b.height) / 2;
  return dx < 0 && dy < 0;
}

function aabbRandom(w, h, pagew, pageh) {
  // return random AABB of given size and must fit page
  return {
    x: Math.round(Math.random() * (pagew - w)),
    y: Math.round(Math.random() * (pageh - h)),
    width: w,
    height: h
  };
}

function aabbDistance(a, b) {
  // Minimal distance between to separated AABB
  var ca = {
      x: a.x + a.width / 2,
      y: a.y + a.height / 2
    },
    cb = {
      x: b.x + b.width / 2,
      y: b.y + b.height / 2
    },
    dx = Math.abs(ca.x - cb.x) - (a.width + b.width) / 2,
    dy = Math.abs(ca.y - cb.y) - (a.height + b.height) / 2;
  return Math.max(dx, dy);
}

function placeNear(a, b, w, h) {
  // Place element of given width and height near A but not intersect B
  var t1 = Date.now(),
    c = document.createElement('div'),
    ra = a.getBoundingClientRect(),
    rb = b.getBoundingClientRect(),
    rc,
    i,
    m = 1e9,
    d,
    best;

  for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    rc = aabbRandom(w, h, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    if (!aabbIntersects(rc, ra) && !aabbIntersects(rc, rb)) {
      // find minimal distance to a
      d = aabbDistance(ra, rc);
      if (d < m && d >= 0) {
        m = d;
        best = rc;
      }
    }
  }
  //console.log(Date.now() - t1);
  c.style.position = 'fixed';
  c.style.width = w + 'px';
  c.style.height = h + 'px';
  c.style.border = '1px solid blue';
  c.style.boxSizing = 'border-box';
  c.style.left = best.x + 'px';
  c.style.top = best.y + 'px';
  c.textContent = 'blue';
  document.body.appendChild(c);
}

placeNear(
  document.getElementById('red'),
  document.getElementById('green'),
  60,
  50
);
```

```html
<div id="green" style="position: fixed; left: 100px; top: 10px; width: 120px; height: 130px; border: 1px solid green; box-sizing: border-box;">green</div>
<div id="red" style="position: fixed; left: 90px; top: 150px; width: 110px; height: 30px; border: 1px solid red; box-sizing: border-box;">red</div>
```

I'm looking for something "proper".

Comment: Could you please share the code with us what you have tried so far? It would be really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: I have few cases manually covered. If first element is button3 and second element is div5, place it to the right of button3, "height"px above div5. I covered few cases like this but is not sufficient and something that could be extracted from it.

Comment: You already reduced your "page" question to the actual problem: you need a 2D box placement algorithm. So... search for that? The fact that it has to work "on a page" is irrelevant, find _any_ website that explains or even provides code for 2D box placement without overlap, and then apply that new knowledge to your programming language of choice, which in this case is Javascript.

Comment: Also note that while center-distance comparison seems clever, it's the bad kind of clever: your code uses 20 operations, some with function call oveheard, whereas the naive bounds check that we can do because you're using AABB, `return ((b2.x <= b1.x && b1.x <= b2.X) || (b1.x <= b2.x && b2.x <= b1.X)) && ((b2.y <= b1.y && b1.y <= b2.Y) || (b1.y <= b2.y && b2.y <= b1.Y))` uses 25% fewer operations (15) and requires zero function calls.

Comment: @Mike Nice example how not to do it: You saved one call to a well tested function that find intersection, and replaced it with your broken version (.Y?). When I'm solving problem, I don't want to question myself if clever one-liner for such a trivial thing as finding box intersection contains error, I'm trying to solve problem, not reinvent basic building blocks.

Comment: yes, capital for max, lowercase for min, and then _you replace it as appropriate for the struct you actually have_ because it could be minx or xmin or .min.x or etc. etc. There's nothing clever about this, this is the less clever universal AABB box intersection detector. You'll have probably already seen it if you went through lots of papers.

Comment: @asdjfiasd, thx! my take on aabbIntersects: `(nodeA, nodeB) => {
  const addCenter = (rect) => Object.assign(rect, { centerX: rect.x + rect.width / 2, centerY: rect.y + rect.height / 2})
  const rectA = addCenter(nodeA.getBoundingClientRect().toJSON())
  const rectB = addCenter(nodeB.getBoundingClientRect().toJSON())
  return Math.abs(rectA.centerX - rectB.centerX) - (rectA.width + rectB.width) / 2 < 0 && Math.abs(rectA.centerY - rectB.centerY) - (rectA.height + rectB.height) / 2 < 0
}`